# How to pass a parameter with parentheses to Powershell from command line?

Tags: mysql, powershell, command-line-arguments

I have a Powershell script called `MSSQLStartStopServices.ps1` used to stop some SQL Server services. This script is being called using a third-party vendor software. The parameters in question are `Fully qualified instance name` and `Start|Stop`

e.g.

```
MSSQLStartStopServices.ps1 HOSTNAME\INSTANCENAME Start
```

For a default instance, the software passes (local) as the INSTANCENAME.

```
MSSQLStartStopServices.ps1 HOSTNAME\(local) Start
```

But when I run this I get an error from Powershell:

> The term 'local' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

When I try and put the instance name in quotes it works fine in a Powershell window:

```
MSSQLStartStopServices.ps1 "HOSTNAME\(local)" Start
```

However the third party software calls Powershell from the commandline first, like so:

```
powershell .\MSSQLStartStopServices.ps1 "HOSTNAME\(local)" Start
```

This causes the same error as if the quotes were not there.

**How do I work around this issue?**

Comment: Surround all your command and params with quotes powershell ".\MSSQLStartStopServices.ps1 HOSTNAME\(local) Start"

Comment: typo Surround all your command and params with quotes powershell `".\MSSQLStartStopServices.ps1 'HOSTNAME(local)' Start`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try enclosing your script-call in double quotes and then each parameter in single quotes:

```
".\MSSQLStartStopServices.ps1" 'HOSTNAME\(local)' 'Start'
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this information for any future people with a smiliar issue finding this page:

In case you want to use a variable as a parameter value that contains characters such as "(" or "|", you need to do it like this:
`-parameter_name ("'" + $variable + "'")`

This worked for me since powershell would remove any double quotes added to the string when calling a non powershell method.